# Modifying a command in a footer not working correctly

Tags: macros, page-breaking, fancyhdr, everyshi

I'm making a document with LaTeX and I wish to add a lateral index to each page with the first letters of the first and last words.

To do that, I need to reset a command at the end of every page

I put a snippet of code in footer (of the `fancyhdr` package) with:

```
\fancyfoot[C]{
\def\TwoFirstLettersBegin{Indef} % Resetting the command
\TwoFirstLettersBegin            % Showing the new state of the command
}
```

but when I build my document, something strange happens:

My command seams to have been correctly resetted and the right content (`Indef`) when it is shown in the footer.
But in the next page, when I print the command, nothings seems to have been modified.

In my pages content, I regularly modify other commands and every thing is nice. I don't understand what I made wrong.

Do you have any idea why my new command definition work in the footer and is cancelled in the next page?

Comment: Most likely the footer is grouped somehow, hence the definition also remains local according to that group. Maybe try using `\gdef...`

Comment: In general I would recommend to use the `everyshi` package for such things, resp. its `\EveryShipout` command.

Comment: Technically your centre footer should show `Indef` from the point onward where you call it that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think using `fancyhdr` for this is kind of a misuse. The `everyshi` package was actually designed for the exact purpose of performing actions right before the page gets shipped out.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
  \fancyfoot[C]{\TwoFirstLettersBegin}
\usepackage{everyshi}
  \EveryShipout{\gdef\TwoFirstLettersBegin{Indef}}

\def\TwoFirstLettersBegin{}
\newcommand\setfirstletters[1]{\gdef\TwoFirstLettersBegin{#1}}

\pagestyle{fancy}

\begin{document}
\setfirstletters{Indef}
\verb|\TwoFirstLettersBegin|: \TwoFirstLettersBegin

\setfirstletters{Foo}
\verb|\TwoFirstLettersBegin|: \TwoFirstLettersBegin

\setfirstletters{Bar}
\verb|\TwoFirstLettersBegin|: \TwoFirstLettersBegin

\clearpage

On the new page it's resetted -- \verb|\TwoFirstLettersBegin|: \TwoFirstLettersBegin
\end{document}
```